# Best way to debug slow MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, performance, connection

I have a program that runs fine with an exact copy of the MySQL data within our own network. However running on a client's server and network every single MySQL operation is significantly slower.

It leads me to believe this is something about either: The MySQL configuration, The server itself, The network.

What is the most effective way to debug this? So far I'm thinking:

1. Ping between hosts running program and server
2. Check server resources
3. Look at MySQL config

Note I am not looking at debugging queries or the software itself as I've pretty much ruled this out as the problem.

We did try to get the client's IT company to look at this, but they don't believe anything is wrong with the network. Unfortunately my networking knowledge is limited but it's up to us / me to prove there is a problem :(

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for SO. That said, I would start by checking a sample query executed using client on the MySQL server itself. If it returns quickly there, then start looking at network related issues.

Comment: Additional DB information request from client's host, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In this case while there were some network issues, stupidly I missed the fact that some of the tables were missing indexes. Presumably my local copy of the database already had these indexes in place. I guess it's just worth double checking the basics in case something has been overlooked.